# Linking checkboxes to text inputs and updating its fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, label

I am trying to link a checkbox to a text input in order to update the value inside the input field.
My problem is how do I update the value accordingly when the checkbox is ticked. For example, I would like to have a text stating status is "Pending" (with the checkbox unticked) and once the box is ticked, update the value to "Completed" and possibly highlight the text input to a green colour.

**Picture:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
    <div class="status-updates">
        <label class="radio" for="status-updates">
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="statuses">
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="pending-completed" id="pending-completed" class="pending-completed" placeholder="Pending">
    </div>
```

Do I need some sort of jQuery to run some sort of input validation?

Would appreciate some help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below jquery code(bind `.change()` event of checkbox) :-

```
$('#statuses').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    $("#pending-completed").attr('placeholder','Completed')
  }
  else
  {
    $("#pending-completed").attr('placeholder','Pending')
  }
});
```

---

EDIT(Placeholder with green color) :-

Jquery :

```
$('#statuses').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    $("#pending-completed").attr('placeholder','Completed').addClass('green-class')
  }
  else
  {
    $("#pending-completed").attr('placeholder','Pending').removeClass('green-class')
  }
});
```

CSS :

```
.green-class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qk964or/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way of updating the text inside of the text input instead of through the placeholder? Possibly doing it through `content`?

Comment: @Jeiman...yes you can use value of textbox instead of placeholder..sorry for late response there is some internet connection problem here

Comment: But I need to declare the value of the textbox within the jQuery right? else, it will be an empty input field, correct?

Comment: @Jeiman...see this fiddle with green text color   http://jsfiddle.net/xgjjcwmL/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and tips. I did some tweaks to the code you made. Now, I would like to disable the text input from users messing around with it. So in the end, I want a textbox with values changing without altering the updated fields from the jQuery -- [jsfiddle.net/xgjjcwmL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xgjjcwmL/2/)

Comment: @Jeiman..sorry but i didn't get you..i visited your link i think the code is working as you want???

Comment: it works after I have ticked the checkbox. Before hand, the user is still able to fill in any value into the text input. How do I solve that or is it impossible to do so ?

Comment: Yeah, sort of now I am trying to replicate this checkboxes multiple times for separate entities. So each checkboxes will be independently on its own. But, after replicating it, it seems to be applying the same format for all of the checkboxes. Trying to make them separate on its own. Care to share your thoughts? [jsfiddle.net/xgjjcwmL/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/xgjjcwmL/5/)

Comment: Ah cool, works good. Would you mind explaining what this syntax does `.parent().siblings`? I'm not too familiar with jQuery just yet. :)

Comment: with .parent().siblings  it will just see parent of checkbox which is label and then it will see label's siblings with class '.pending-completed'..@Jeiman

Comment: - I see Ok. Awesome. thanks alot for the help buddy. Really appreciated it! :D Sorry for the late reply, couldnt send out the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : bind `change` event to checkbox and put placeholder as per checkbox checked status.

```
$(function(){
 $('#statuses').change(function(){
    var placeholder = $(this).is(':checked')?"Completed":"Pending";

    $("#pending-completed").attr('placeholder',placeholder);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/don/qaxow1jz/

---

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[name=status]').change(function() {
    var inputText = 'input[name=pending-completed]';
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(inputText).attr('placeholder', 'Completed').addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $(inputText).attr('placeholder', 'Pending').removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="status-updates">
    <label class="radio" for="status-updates">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="statuses">
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="pending-completed" id="pending-completed" class="pending-completed" placeholder="Pending">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input.highlight[name=pending-completed]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
input.highlight[name=pending-completed]:-moz-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
input.highlight[name=pending-completed]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
input.highlight[name=pending-completed]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this . Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/gmwzzL10/

HTML

```
    <div class="status-updates">
        <label class="radio" for="status-updates">
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="statuses" class="checkbox_status">
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="pending-completed" id="pending-completed" class="pending-completed" placeholder="Pending">
    </div>
```

JS

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $(".checkbox_status").click(function(){
        var inputBox = $(this).closest(".status-updates").find(".pending-completed");

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
             inputBox.attr("placeholder","Completed").addClass("make-green");
        }
       else{
            inputBox.attr("placeholder","Pending").removeClass("make-green");
       }
    })

})
```

CSS

```
.make-green{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```